# Angular-Jasmine, loading json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, requirejs, jasmine

I am trying to load json from local folder and then feed it into function to test it. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
it('should be able to use treatExpResultJSON() function to treat incoming JSON', function() {
   require(['./jsonSampleData.json'], function(json){
      expect(dirService.treatExpResultJSON(json)).not.toBeNull();
      expect(dirService.treatExpResultJSON(json)).not.toBeUndefined();
      console.log(json);
      console.log("Testing json passed!");
   });   

});
```

`expect` is not working inside the `require` callback function, I guess, it is not called at all since with both `.not.toBeNull()`, `not.toBeUndefined()` and `.toBeNull()`, `toBeUndefined()` the test is showing success. Also, `console.log()` are not working inside the function. So, how should I actually load the json, then supply it to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
json = require('./jsonSampleData.json');

it('should be able to use treatExpResultJSON() function to treat incoming JSON', function() {
  expect(dirService.treatExpResultJSON(json)).not.toBeNull();
  expect(dirService.treatExpResultJSON(json)).not.toBeUndefined();
  console.log(json);
  console.log("Testing json passed!");
});
```

I use this structure in my tests, and works.